# Create/Update a .json file in a github repo from Javascript (Google Apps Script)?

Tags: javascript, json, git, github, google-apps-script

I have a `.json` file in my repo that I need to keep up to date with google sheets automatically (When sheets is updated, so should my remote repo). Currently my approach has been to use Googles Apps Script to create a Json formatted dictionary whenever an edit has been made but have no way of transferring this data to github or bitbucket*.

Any information on how this could be achieved is greatly appreciated!

**The repo is bitbucket but happy to send it to a github repo then fetch this as a submodule if required.*

Comment: If you are using Github you can use the GitHub API: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents Your Google App Script should be able to call this

Comment: @TheIceBear Thanks for your comment, I did look into that but Google App Scripts is weird with libaries and getting to a point where it would even be able to use rest is tricky.

I ended up using Google Drive but now having issues adding it as a submodule lol